# Rearranging formulas involving fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm currently studying some basic algebra (Not sure what the equivalent is for the US etc) in school currently.

I'm having trouble with rearranging certain formulas.

I attempted to try and solve the questions below and I'll show my working ut but the answers are consistently incorrect.

1. If $R = \dfrac{1}{R_1} + \dfrac{1}{R_2}$, what is the value of $R_1$ given that $R = 1.15$ and $R_2 = 2.30$?

I tried subtracting $\dfrac{1}{R_2}$ from $R$ seen here:

$$R - \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_1}$$ 
but realised that I'm not sure how to get $R_1$ by itself.

Also tried:

$$RR_2 = \frac{1}{R_1}$$

but unsure how to divide a fraction by a fraction.

Could someone help explain how to rearrange an equation like this?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thank you! @N.F.Taussig - Apologise for that, fairly new to the site and wasn't too sure on how to format it correctly, I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$R-\frac{1}{R_1}=\frac{1}{R_2}$$
$$\frac{RR_1-1}{R_1}=\frac{1}{R_2}$$
thus we obtain $$R_2=\frac{R_1}{R_1R-1}$$